# Autowired not working if used inside class that extends Spring security class

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I wasn't able to "autowire" inside a class that extends Spring security class (org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler).

I made it working by adding, in security-config.xml, the following code, already written inside the xml spring configuration file: `<context:annotation-config />`, `<context:component-scan base-package="packagename...."/>` and the beans that I autowired.

I have two questions:

1. Why have I to write twice that code (both inside the xml spring
   configuration file and security-config.xml)
2. Is there a way to tell security-config.xml to "look" for the code
   written inside the xml spring configuration file? This way I
   shouldn't write the code twice.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: No there isn't nor should you want that. Also `<context:componet-scanning />` already implies `<context:annotation-config/>`. You need to specify it once for each application context, both the `DispatcherServlet` and `ContextLoaderListener` create their own `ApplicationContext` and for both you would have to enable annotation processing.

Comment: you can import your security.xml from your beans.xml. then you will not have to declare it twice.

Comment: I was trying using import but i get an error because spring tells me it can't find ds-servlet.xml. I have to import ds-servlet.xml inside security-config.xml. The problem is that security-config.xml is inside subfolder of WEB-INF. What's the path i should import?
I added a pic of my project

Comment: @MatteoDepasquali what is ds-servlet??

Comment: i meant spring configuration file

Comment: does this solve you issue? if not, paste here your XMLs ...

Comment: Don't import the full context as that leads to bean duplication!

Comment: @M.Deinum please see my comment to you, after my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to import your security-beans.xml from your main beans.xml.

Both files should be in the same folder. the import, for example:

> ```
> <import resource="spring-security.xml"/>
> ```

In your web.xml, write something like this:

```
<!-- to integrate Spring -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

### 2nd Approach - single beans.xml

Another approach, if you are afraid of imports, is to hold a single beans.xml that will include all beans - both the security beans as well as other beans. In this case, your web.xml will look like this:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.spring</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and your spring beans file will be spring-servlet.xml.

HTH.

Comment: Importing might appear to fix the problem BUT that also duplicates all beans. Not something you want as it only takes up memory and might lead to other suprises...

Comment: @M.Deinum I totally agree with you that beans duplication is a bad practice. Having said that, beans in spring-security.xml should not duplicate beans in the main beans.xml, and then you can safely import. Am I missing something?

Comment: If you import `spring-servlet.xml` into `spring-security.xml`. The `ContextLoaderListener` will load all beans in both the context files. Next the `DispatcherServlet` will load the `spring-servlet.xml` again loading the beans in there. Importing the `spring-security.xml` in the `DispatcherServlet` makes things even worse as you now have duplicated security the spring security filter using one and the servlet using another instance. This can lead to very nice unexpected effects.

Comment: thanks @M.Deinum; usually , i work with a single beans.xml, and the security beans are there, too. is it a bad practice too?

Comment: Depends if you load it twice or not. If that is only loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener` there isn't an issue if you imported it into the context loaded by the `DispatcherServlet` as well you have effectivly duplicated all your beans (or loaded it otherwise there).

Comment: i've pasted above an example to my web.xml. this is how is load spring. it is loaded by the DispatcherServlet. and note the "filter". is it a bad practice?

Comment: The filter never loads anything only a `ContextLoaderListener` which you don't appear to have. You load everything in your `DispatcherServlet` and tell the filter to use the context loaded from that. That shouldn't be a problem.